# «Никого не будет в доме...» Пунктуация. Значение слова «моховой»

Tags: пунктуация, значение-слов, поэзия, выбор-варианта

Всем известны эти строки Б. Л. Пастернака. Обнаружилось несколько вариантов стихотворения, различающихся пунктуационно (привожу только два).

[I.](https://rupoem.ru/pasternak/nikogo-ne-budet.aspx)
. . .
*Только белых мокрых комьев

Быстрый промельк моховой,* [точка или запятая]
*Только крыши, снег, и, кроме* [запятая перед "и"]
*Крыш и снега, никого.*
. . .
*Но нежданно по портьере

Пробежит сомненья дрожь, —* [запятая перед тире]
*Тишину шагами меря.* [точка или запятая]
*Ты, как будущность, войдешь.*

*Ты появишься из двери

В чем-то белом, без причуд,

В чем-то, впрямь из тех материй,* [запятая после "чем-то"]
*Из которых хлопья шьют.*

[II.](http://www.poetarium.info/pasternak/none.htm)
. . .
*Только белых мокрых комьев

Быстрый промельк моховой.

Только крыши, снег и, кроме* [тире после "и"]
*Крыш и снега, — никого.*
. . .
*Но нежданно по портьере

Пробежит вторженья дрожь.* [точка или другой знак?]
*Тишину шагами меря,

Ты, как будущность, войдешь.*

*Ты появишься у двери

В чем-то белом, без причуд,

В чем-то впрямь из тех материй,

Из которых хлопья шьют.*

1. Подскажите: какая пунктуация правильна?
2. Каково значение слова **моховой** (в этом контексте)?

Comment: Ау, люди! Может, кто-то найдет авторитетное печатное издание?

Comment: Здесь нужно не авторитетное печатное издание, а нечто иное. Стихотворение «Никого не будет в доме» было написано в 1931 г. Оно вошло в изданный в 1932 г. сборник «Второе рождение». Вот этот сборник надо найти.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова А промельк моховой или маховой? Например: https://www.stihi.ru/2016/11/29/3555    В одном тексте разные варианты.

Comment: Много лет я считала, что правильно **маховой** (такая "трактовка" была мне ближе и понятней). Столкнулось с О (а таких вариантов большинство!) и странной пунктуацией. Задала вопрос. "Сильно много" рассуждать не решаюсь, чтобы не попасть в категорию _какие-то непрофессиональные бегемоты_.

Comment: А вопрос-то "сильно интересный". Такое впечатление, что кто-то правит текст по своему усмотрению. А вот почему - это вопрос. Может  быть, оригинал не сохранился? У кого спросить-то, как Вы думаете?

Comment: И что такое "промельк маховой"?  Размашистый, от угла до угла стекла? Или это всё-таки промельк  мшистого снега?

Comment: Но ведь комья-то мокрые, именно комья, а не комочки  пушистые, здесь явно отрицательная коннотация, а положительная появится, когда увидит любимую (что-то белое, из чего хлопья шьют)

Comment: Да и эпитет относится к промельку, а не к комьям.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Может, кто-то найдет авторитетное печатное издание?
```

Не знаю, насколько авторитетен для Вас сборник "Русская советская поэзия", М., Художественная литература, 1990, под ред. В. Огнева и В. Фогельсона.

Никого не будет в доме,
Кроме сумерек. Один
Зимний день в сквозном проёме
Незадёрнутых гардин.
   ...

Только белых мокрых комьев
Быстрый промельк м**а**ховой. (**точка**)
Только крыши, снег и, кроме (**нет запятой перед "и"**)
Крыш и снега, — никого. (**тире после запятой)**

И опять кольнут доныне
Неотпущенной виной,
И окно по крестовине
Сдавит голод дровяной.

...

Но нежданно по портьере
Пробежит сомненья дрожь. (**точка)**
Тишину шагами меря, (**запятая**)
Ты, как будущность, войдешь.

...

Ты появишься из двери
В чем-то белом, без причуд,
В чем-то впрямь из тех материй, (**нет запятой после "чем-то")**
Из которых хлопья шьют.

Есть ещё брошюрки "Анализ текста", М., Дрофа, 2000. Сопоставила — то же самое.

```
  Каково значение слова моховой (в этом контексте)?
```

Мне это "моховой" сразу не понравилось, поэтому и Вы не поняли его смысл в этом контексте. А вот "промельк м**а**ховой" понятен: снегопад с сильным ветром — "маховой", размашистый, хлопья быстро мелькают перед глазами.

Первая  строфа совершенно статична, в ней нет глаголов. Во второй тоже нет глаголов, но движение есть — снегопад. Представление о нём создаёт отглагольное существительное-неологизм "промельк". Точка после назывного предложения во второй строфе вполне уместна — снегопад как отдельный образ. Крыши, снег вокруг — другой образ. Всё вместе — одиночество, отсутствие уюта ("незадёрнутых гардин").

Четвёртая строфа — это сложное предложение, первая часть которого — односоставное неопределённо-личное, то есть личность тех, кто кольнёт виной, которую не простили, не важна и не интересна. Сам глагол "кольнуть" относится к лирическому герою, который в данной строфе с помощью психологического параллелизма сопоставляется с окном, испытывающим давление «дровяного голода». Глагол сдавит относится уже к деревянным перекладинам окна, которые давят на стекло, но не могут его расколоть.
(1931 г. — время знакомства Пастернака с будущей второй женой, Зинаидой Нейгауз, на тот момент женой Генриха Нейгауза, знаменитого пианиста и друга Пастернака. Для соединения в браке, которое произошло в 1932 г., Пастернаку и Зинаиде Нейгауз придётся пережить тяжёлый развод с прежними мужем и женой. Пастернак оставит сына, а дети пианиста Нейгауза будут жить в семье Зинаиды и Бориса. Отсюда и вина.)

Появление возлюбленной предваряет дрожь вторженья. Портьера — антипод гардины, она плотная и часто висит не на окне, а на двери. Очевидно, эта портьера задёрнута, но она колеблется от шагов. Шаги, появляющиеся в следующей строчке, разрушают тишину, в которой всё это время находился лирический герой. Героиня не только сравнивается с будущностью, но и является будущим лирического героя.
Видимо, поэтому в некоторых изданиях нет запятой перед **как**.

Одежда возлюбленной для лирического героя сливается со снегом за окном, который представляется герою материалом для белых одежд женщины.
Приход лирической героини назван «вторженьем», с ней приходит жизнь. А вокруг все изменяется. «Белых мокрых комьев» теперь нет, а есть снежные хлопья, которые теперь являются единым целым с ней. Ее платье даже не названо платьем, а «чем-то белым», из тех материй, из которых «хлопья шьют». Интонация стихотворения изменяется: грусть, тоска уступают место восторженности и восхищению.

Answer (score 2):

**Только крыши, снег, и, кроме // Крыш и снега, никого.**

Я понимаю так: *Есть только крыши и снег, и, кроме крыш и снега, нет никого.*
Первая запятая ставится, так как это ССП, вторая и третья обособляют сравнительный оборот.

Рассмотрим вариант: *Только крыши, снег и, кроме // Крыш и снега, — никого.*
Убираем сравнительный оборот, получаем: *Только крыши, снег и — никого.*
Раз нет запятой перед *и*, то как будто автор искал, искал еще что-то,  **что относится к "только"**,  но не нашел.

> Но нежданно по портьере
>    Пробежит сомненья дрожь, — [запятая перед тире]
>   Тишину шагами меря. [точка или запятая]
>   Ты, как будущность, войдешь.

Уверенно можно сказать, что точка здесь невозможна, иначе получается, что  дрожь, бегая по портьере, меряет тишину шагами (ха-ха). После *дрожь* я бы поставил двоеточие или тире (но не запятую и тире), так как портьера зашевелится от движения воздуха, когда она войдет.

> [МОХОВОЙ](https://www.vedu.ru/expdic/70857/) прилагательное 1) см. мох, связанный с ним. 2) Свойственный мху, характерный для него. 3) Состоящий из мха.

Думаю, автор считает, что комья снега похожи на комочки мха.

Comment: Сейчас изображу-отмечу.

Comment: Никого не будет в доме,
Кроме сумерек. Один 
Зимний день в сквозном проеме 
Незадернутых гардин. 

Только белых мокрых комьев 
Быстрый промельк маховой. 
Только крыши, снег и, кроме 
Крыш и снега, — никого. 

И опять зачертит иней, 
И опять завертит мной 
Прошлогоднее унынье 
И дела зимы иной, 

И опять кольнут доныне 
Не отпущенной виной, 
И окно по крестовине 
Сдавит голод дровяной.

Comment: Но нежданно по портьере 
Пробежит вторженья дрожь.
Тишину шагами меря, 
Ты, как будущность, войдешь. 

Ты появишься у двери 
В чем-то белом, без причуд, 
В чем-то впрямь из тех материй, 
Из которых хлопья шьют. 

1931 https://slova.org.ru/pasternak/nikogonebudet/  http://www.stihi-rus.ru/love/94.htm

Answer (score 0):

В серии "Великие поэты" (2012 год) используется **вариант с тире,** мне он кажется более убедительным.

**Только крыши, снег и, кроме // Крыш и снега, никого.**

Если убрать оборот: Только крыши, снег и — никого.

Тире обозначает **неожиданное присоединение** еще одного однородного члена в простом предложении.

Comment: Было бы понятно такое: *Крыши, снег и — никого*. Но добавлено *только*. "Только никого" — неуместно.  Поэтому я ратую за запятую перед *и*.

Comment: Никого - это полное отсутствие всего живого. Только крыши, снег и — пустота.

Comment: Только  крыши, снег и пустота? Допустим. Но там еще вставка "кроме крыши и снега". Это разрущает Ваше построение и наводит на мысль об отдельном предложении: "кроме крыши и снега нет никого".

Comment: Как это разрушает? Только крыши, снег и (кроме крыш и снега) — никого (пустота). Всё логично.

Comment: Возьмем что-то попроще. *Яблоко, груша и (кроме яблока и груши) — ничего.* Ну при чем здесь "кроме яблока и груши"? Еще можно понять такое: *Яблоко, груша и ничего, кроме яблока груши.* Но здесь нет  "неожиданного присоединения", а после инверсии получаем *Яблоко, груша и, кроме яблока и груши, ничего.* Такой вариант тоже есть в интернете.

Comment: Вы очень строго оцениваете художественные образы и находки поэта. Придется Вам поискать подлинный вариант. Я надеюсь, что Пастернак на моей стороне (вернее, я на его).