# "И окно по крестовине / Сдавит голод дровяной"

Tags: смысл, поэзия

Раз уж коснулись Пастернака ([«Никого не будет в доме...» Пунктуация. Значение слова «моховой»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447535/%d0%9d%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9)), помогите понять две строчки:

> И окно по крестовине
>   Сдавит голод дровяной.

Answer (score 3):

Я не стала в своем вопросе акцентировать внимание на этих строках. Почему? Потому что я ощутила их так.
Время было отчаянное, жизнь, особенно зимой, — скудная.
Дровяной голод — это отсутствие дров для отопления жилища (не было ничего: ни дров, ни угля, ни торфа для печей).

"...Зимний день в сквозном проеме незадернутых гардин". Сумерки.
Холодно не только на улице (за промёрзшим окном), но и в самом доме: стекла, разделенные крестовиной, покрыты слоем льда с обеих сторон, сжимаются и трещат от мороза...
Голод и холод нарастают (они нестерпимы и бесконечны!), угнетают и давят — давят на всё вокруг.
Воспоминания. Ожидание. "Вторженья дрожь".

Comment: Голод дровяной - это понятно, нет дров, в комнате очень холодно. А вот с окнами никак не разберусь. Деревянные рамы (крестовина) держат стекла, но на холоде стекло сжимается. А дальше одни вопросы. Отчего трещат стекла? Если бы дома было тепло, а на улице сильный мороз, то стекла бы  трещали или нет? Или  может это дерево трещит? У Пастернака сказано только то, что окно (а не стекло) сдавлено по крестовине, но насколько точным является это выражение (сдавлено по крестовине). Срочно нужна консультация физика.

Comment: @ Римма Михайлова  Мне нравится Ваш ответ и Ваше восприятие поэзии, но вот о чем я думаю. Литературные критики очень детально реконструируют чувства поэта (так что не всегда им хочется верить), но это место аккуратно обходят. Насколько точна метафора - вот в чем сила художественного образа, а не в  рассказах на тему "что хотел сказать поэт". А вдруг он совсем не это имел в виду? Иногда мне кажется, что при анализе мы рассказываем о наших собственных чувствах, а не объясняем метафоры. Но ведь другие люди могут испытывать нечто иное, и уж конечно нам сложно "угадать" истинные чувства автора.

Answer (score 1):

И опять кольнут доныне

Неотпущенной виной,

И окно по крестовине

Сдавит голод дровяной.

Как я понимаю, здесь анафора тоже играет свою роль. Оба простых предложения начинаются союзом И - всё в одном ряду: героя давит вина, а окна давит холод. Известно, что зима 1931 года была очень холодной, топить нечем, окно покрывается инеем, особенно по крестовине, на морозе сжимается (от тепла всё расширяется - от холода сужается), бывали случаи, что и трескались окна от мороза, вот и образ: мороз сдавил окно по крестовине, там же иней, снег. Может, и ледяной узор сдавливает, снег ведь летит в окно ("промельк маховой", но ведь не только мелькает перед окном, но и  в окно тоже попадает).

А вот мультик про Снежную Королеву помните? В начале мультфильма, когда рассказчик говорит про необычно сильные морозы, толстый слой инея на окнах, прикладывание к стеклу монетки, нагретой на печке (когда снежная королева заглянула в окно)  По-моему, похожий образ, кажется, что иней сдавливает окно.

Так что Римма права, я поддерживаю её ответ плюсом.

Comment: @ Людмила Извините, а Вы не подскажете, почему окно сдавлено именно по крестовине, а не просто сдавлено? И в каком направлении сдавлено, с боков или с лицевой стороны? У меня никак не получается понять и должным образом оценить эту метафору. Примечание. Вы только не подумуайте, что это какой-то праздный вопрос, я вчера долго пыталась найти на него ответ в Интернете, но безрезультатно. Такое впечатление, что точность метафорического языка не анализируется при разборах.

Comment: В точности метафор Пастернака просто никто не сомневается, ведь метафора всегда субъективна: автор может видеть совсем не то, что мы с вами, а мы иногда даже представить не можем то, что увидел автор, но здесь мне метафора понятна. В холодной квартире в сумерки герой смотрит в окно, видит снег, налипший на крестовину окна (метель же, "промельк маховой"), снег задерживается именно на крестовине. Если б тепло было в комнате, с окна бы потекла вода, а сейчас холодно, с внутренней стороны тоже стекло замёрзло, вот и  сдавливает его с двух сторон.

Comment: Не очень понятно, но всё равно спасибо.  Всё-таки надеюсь, что какой-нибудь физик откликнется и тоже даст свое объяснение

Comment: Физик-то оказался как раз и не нужен, Вы добивались, чтобы кто-то сказал, что крестовина - сердце окна (середина, основа). Но ведь мы тоже пытались сказать, что герой и окно здесь сопоставлены по ощущениям - это приём психологического  параллелизма.

Comment: Да, наверное, да и вряд ли физики сюда заглядывают.

Comment: @Sharon, я не физик, но физику учил.  "Сдавливание окна по крестовине" — давление направлено на крестовину. Сравните: сдавливание по центру прямоугольника (крестовина находится в центре окна).

Comment: @М_Г Допустим, Вы учили физику, но почему Вы задали вопрос и исчезли? Я два дня у всех расспрашивала, как действует мороз на стекла и отчего они трещат. С точки зрения физики и сейчас не всё понятно (как там эти силы распределяются), а вот метафора  ясна. Понятно, почему крестовина, а не просто деревянная рама окна. Мы для Вас просто ребус разгадали, а Вы даже не поблагодарили нас за это. Ну да ладно, мы не обиделись.

Comment: @Sharon Я всем поставил +1, а писать "спасибо" справка не велит. Я  думаю, вы все и так чувствуете, как я вам признателен и с каким удовольствием читаю ваши ответы. Но не всегда успеваю  реагировать, все-таки это всего лишь хобби...

Comment: Хорошо, а то мне почему-то показалось, что Вы ждали от ответов большего, ну как бы мы Вам ничего нового не сказали. Но это не так важно, зато мы сами стали лучше понимать поэзию Пастернака, он стал нам ближе. Спасибо Вам за интересный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

**Объяснение метафоры**

**Текст:**

И опять зачертит иней,
И опять завертит мной
 **Прошлогоднее унынье**
 И **дела зимы иной**.

И опять **кольнут** доныне
Не отпущенной виной,
И окно п**о крестовине
 Сдавит** голод дровяной...

**Объяснение**

**"Дела зимы иной" холодом кольнут в самое сердце  и сдавят грудь.**

А дальше идет  **скрытое сравнение**: так же холод **с двух сторон** давит **в середину** оконного стекла (тоже "в сердце", **по крестовине**).

Вот теперь метафора **кажется мне точной:** ни одного лишнего слова, всё на месте.

Comment: Может, и так, каждый понимает по-своему, акцентирует своё внимание на отдельных деталях. Что здесь психологический параллелизм - это точно, видимо, мы с Риммой просто не стали касаться чувств - это же понятно: ему на сердце давит вина, на окно давит холод. Просто Вы  поставили под сомнение точность  метафоры, поэтому мы стали объяснять, что она точна внешне, с точки зрения наблюдателя.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, всё нормально.  Меня просто эта крестовина смущала, мешала разобраться.

Comment: Sharon, @Людмила Холод давит в сердце окна, как вина сжимает сердце человека.  Но почему голод, а не холод? Причем нехватка дров к чувству вины?

Comment: Так ведь это метафорический перифраз  голод дровяной = холод (в комнате). Состояния окна и героя параллельны, сердца их сдавлены - у одного холодом физическим, у другого холодом душевным, чувством вины перед семьёй.

Comment: @Людмила, Написал бы Пастернак "холод ледяной" — спал бы я спокойно по начам, а теперь все никак не могу успокоиться. Не оставляет меня ассоциация с голодными спазмами.

Comment: @М_Г Ну да, та ещё метафора. Голод дровяной (боже! как он может выглядеть!) сначала сдавит окно, а потом и самого жильца прохладной комнаты.